# How can I get HDMI audio to be visible to `aplay -l` on Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, hdmi, nvidia-geforce, alsa

I've got a new machine with an Nvidia GeForce 210 graphics card with HDMI output.  I'm trying to get sound to go out that HDMI cable, but although the device shows up on lspci, I can't get it acknowledged by `aplay -l`, which lists the audio devices known to the audio driver.

lspci shows (in part):

```
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

The first is the motherboard audio, and it works fine.  The second (I assume) is the graphics card with HDMI.  But `aplay -l` lists only the motherboard analog and S/PDIF outputs:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC887 Analog [ALC887 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC887 Digital [ALC887 Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I can't see how I'm going to select a device that the drivers think isn't there.
Any idea **how to make that device visible to the sound drivers?**

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 with a 2.6.32 stock kernel.  The Nvidia driver version is 195.36.24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [this](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO_set_up_HDMI_audio_on_nVidia_GeForce_G210,_GT220,_or_GT240).

Comment: Looks brilliant, thanks.  It's after midnight here; I'll check it out tomorrow. +1

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams **The link is dead.**